# Convert AVRO container file to JSON

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, avro

I have a bunch of AVRO files in an S3 bucket. Each file contains a series of records. Every time a file is uploaded to the Bucket, a Lambda is triggered. I want to read the content of the AVRO file (the records) and save them in a more friendly format, for instance push all entries to an array so I could do stuff with it.

I am using the client-s3 from the aws-sdk lib.

I have tried with the following piece of code but I am not able to get a working result.

```js
let client = new S3Client({})
let command = new GetObjectCommand(parameters)

const { Body } = await client.send(command)
```

I have tried other solutions too that I found on the Internet and AWS Docs but I do not seem to find a way to make this work.

Comment: The `Body` in the response is a stream. If that doesn't help you, please provide more information such as how your code fails (all you said was that it doesn't work).